# Shifting rows down in discontinuous range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with a Range that consists of multiple areas, e.g.,

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Application.Union(Range("A1:C5"),Range("A11:C15"))
```

The range will have some number of nonempty rows at the top and empty rows at the bottom, and I'd like to be able to shift the non-empty rows down by 1 to allow a new entry in the first row. **Edit: The shift should go across the "break" in the areas, i.e., the last row of the first area should shift down into the first row of the second area.**

If I had a continuous range, then I could do this as follows:

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("A1:C10")
Dim j as Integer
[Some code to set j equal to the index of the last non-empty row]
With rng1
    .Parent.Range(.Cells(2,1), .Cells(j+1,3)).Value2 = .Parent.Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(j,3)).Value2
    .Parent.Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(1,3)).ClearContents
End With
```

However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this cleanly when the range is split into two areas. One idea I had was to define an array `rowindex(1 To 10)` with `rowindex(1)=1`,..., `rowindex(5)=5`,`rowindex(6)=11`,..., `rowindex(10)=15` and then use `rowindex(j)` in place of `j`. This won't allow me to shift everything down in one step like above, but I could do it row-by-row as:

```
Dim i as Integer
With rng
    For i = j To 1 Step -1
        .Parent.Range(.Cells(rowindex(i+1),1), .Cells(rowindex(i+1),3).Value2  = _
            .Parent.Range(.Cells(rowindex(i),1), .Cells(rowindex(i),3)).Value2
    Next i
    .Parent.Range(.Cells(rowindex(1),1), .Cells(rowindex(1),1)).ClearContents
End With
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to do the shift in one step (i.e., remove the `For i =` loop)?
2. Is there a "better" solution than my `rowindex` array (i.e., faster to run, less code, more readable, etc.)? One downside to my solution is that I'm hardcoding the values of `rowindex` rather than taking them from `rng`. I think this could be fixed by doing something like:

```
Dim k As Integer
k = 1
For Each row In rng.Rows
    rowindex(k) = row.Cells.Row
    k = k + 1
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Areas` property of a `Range` object, which lists each component of a `Range`.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.areas

This code provides a sample multi-range.

```
Dim myRange As Range
Cells.Clear
Range("a1:c3") = 1
Range("e5:f6") = 2
Set myRange = Union(Range("a1:c3"), Range("e5:f6"))
myRange = 5
```

After that, we loop through each area one at a time using the `Areas` collection, and use your code to shift each `Area` individually.

```
For Each a In myRange.Areas
With a
j = a.Rows(1).Row + a.Rows.Count - 1
    .Parent.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(j + 1, 3)).Value2 = .Parent.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(j, 3)).Value2
    .Parent.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 3)).ClearContents
End With
Next a
```

The `j` variable stores the last row index in the sub-range (first row index + number of rows - 1).

Comment: This does not accomplish what I want. I might have been unclear in my question, but I need the last row of the first area to shift down into the first row of the second area. With your code it just spills into the row below the first range.